# ComponentQuery for specific listitem

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to create a controller with a ref to a specific item in a List, is this possible?

So really I need the ComponentQuery to reference a listitem. I am setting the data inline in the list:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
    extend : 'Ext.List',
    alias : 'widget.mylist',

    config : {
        title : 'Title',

        itemTpl : ['{displayName}'].join(''),

        data : [{
            displayName : 'One',
            id : 1
        }, {
            displayName : 'Two',
            id : 2
        }, {
            displayName : 'Three',
            id : 3
        }, {
            displayName : 'Four',
            id : 4
        }]
    }
});
```

Then on in my controller (this is obviously not working):

```
refs : {
    oneListItem: 'mylist.list[id=1]',
    twoListItem: 'mylist.list[id=2]',
    threeListItem: 'mylist.list[id=3]',
    fourListItem: 'mylist.list[id=4]'
}
```

Hopefully this is possible. If it is not I can listen for an 'itemtap' on the list and call a method from there, however, I would prefer not have to do that for cleanliness.

Thanks in advance.

Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: adding `id` to the objects in your data section will not have any effect, that is just the data that's taken and substituted in the `itemTpl` you specified before.

As to your question: Sencha Touch 2 Documentation does not mention a way to have `Ext.ComponentQuery` select the n-th child of a `Component`, so, assuming you want to create your list objects with inline data, the only way I see is to use the `id` that Sencha automatically applies to each listItem on creation.

These ids are of the `#ext-listitem-1` kind, see an example of how to use them in this [Sencha Fiddle demo](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/NzDOV/).

This is however bad practice, because you cannot rely on those id, if for example you add another list to your application they can change breaking your code.

I do not see any valid reason why you shouldn't use itemtap to act on the list, since with the event you get all the data you need to manipulate the proper list item:

```
itemtap( this, index, target, record, e, eOpts )
```

For completeness sake, I must mention that you could also add your items dynamically with Ext.dataview.List.add(), that way you should be able to create your `dataitems` with a custom `id`.

Comment: You're 100% right, I didn't ask hoping for a hack or non-standard solution. I was just hoping I had missed something in the documentation.

Thank you for the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `Ext.select('.x-list-item-first');` or `Ext.select('.x-list-item-last');` if you want a handle on the first or last item.  I would encourage you to add an xtype set to "mylist" instead of using alias.

Comment: I will try that when I get back into the office, looks promising. Regarding using xtypes in place of alias...I believe you but I don't quite understand why. Is there any documentation you can point me to? Thanks!

Comment: I do not see how could this work: `mylist > .list-item-1` selects all childs of xtype `mylist` that have xtype `.list-item-1`. The xtype  of a `Ext.dataview.component.ListItemView` is just `listitem` isnt'it?

Comment: That's the CSS selector I was referring to (but for Sencha Touch it's different).  You could do this: Ext.select('.x-list-item-first'), assuming you want the first item.